# Centering an image in a horizontal navigation menu

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center an image in the middle of my navigation menu, while also trying to keep the entire menu centered vertically in the middle of the page.

Also, every time I place in the image, the text goes to the bottom instead of being aligned with the vertical center of the image.

Here is the html:

```
<body>
      <div id="centered">
<ul>
    <li><a href="link1.html">LINK1</a></li>
    <li><a href="link2.html">LINK2</a></li>
    <li><img src="http://prettylushrecords.comoj.com/sampleimage.jpg"></li>
    <li><a href="link3.html">LINK3</a></li>
    <li><a href="link4.html">LINK4</a></li>
</ul>     
</div>
   </body>
```

Here is the the CSS:

```
html, body  { 
    background-color: white; 
    height: 100%; 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
    color: white; 
}

#centered { 
    border: none; 
    background: white; 
    height: 150px; 
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -75px;
}

#centered ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: 58px;
    padding: 0;
} 

#centered li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 20px 0 20px;
    font-family: Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#centered li a { 
    text-decoration: none; 
    color: #000;
    /*transition: color 0.2s linear;*/
}
#centered li a:hover {
    color: #bdb0b0;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/chassen2/n84ey/11/

Answer (score 0):

You can center something in css by using vertical-align: middle (together with display: table-cell).

```
<div style="display: table;">
    <div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">
    </div>
</div>
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/RS78Y/

Maybe it will help you.